# Visual Studio Community 2013 Update 4 Setup failed

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2013, installation, windows-installer

I have downloaded **Visual Studio Community 2013 Update 4 iso** file from **visualstudio.com** to install VS on **Windows 8.1 x64** and I have verfied SHA1 checksum of the iso file and the result was correct.

The problem was that  setup stops at Applying: Visual Studio Core features and then fail and finalize with

-Error icon and "Visual Studio Core Features -ENU Fatal error during installation"

-Warning icons on three messages which were : "Microsoft Visual C++ 2013 32bit Compilers - ENU Resource Package failed", "Microsoft Visual C++ 2013 Compilers - ENU Resource Package failed" and "Microsoft Visual C++ 2013 x64 Native Compilers - ENU Resource Package failed"

Until now I have done the following :-

1) Disabled Antivirus,Firewall and Anti-Malware before installation and run installation as Administartor.

2) Cleaned %temp%,C:\ProgramData\Package Cache and AppData\Local\Temp folders before installation.

3) Verified all installed .Net frameworks using .Net Framewrok setup verfication utility.

4) Used the system file checker tool to repair missing or corrupted system files as descriped in https://support.microsoft.com/KB/929833 and the result was "Windows Resource Protection did not find any integrity violations".

And found these errors in logs (ERROR is coming from **vs_professionalcore.msi**) :-

AppData\Local\Temp\dd_vs_community_20141221193705.log

```
[0B88:12C4][2014-12-21T19:45:57]i000: MUX:  Installation size in bytes for package: vs_professionalcore MaxAppDrive: 0  MaxSysDrive: 1821361272  AppDrive: 0  SysDrive: 1335334008
[0B88:12C4][2014-12-21T19:45:57]i000: MUX:  Return Code:0x0 Msi Messages:0 Result Detail:RollbackCleanup Restart:None
[0B88:12C4][2014-12-21T19:45:57]i000: MUX:  Reset execution Result
[0B88:12C4][2014-12-21T19:45:57]i000: MUX:  Reset Result
[0B88:12C4][2014-12-21T19:45:57]i319: Applied execute package: vs_professionalcore, result: 0x0, restart: None
[0E44:1184][2014-12-21T19:45:57]i325: Registering dependency: {96a8b90c-0a91-4e76-ab34-730c23923d11} on package provider: Microsoft.VS.professionalcore,v12, package: vs_professionalcore
[0B88:12C4][2014-12-21T19:45:57]i000: MUX:  ExecutePackageBegin PackageId: vs_professionalcoreres
[0E44:1184][2014-12-21T19:45:57]i301: Applying execute package: vs_professionalcoreres, action: Install, path: C:\ProgramData\Package Cache\{E9674444-9491-3961-873C-017D8912185E}v12.0.21005\packages\professionallp\vs_professionalcoreres.msi, arguments: ' ARPSYSTEMCOMPONENT="1" MSIFASTINSTALL="7" VSEXTUI="1" INSTALLINGBUNDLE="community" PATCH="C:\ProgramData\Package Cache\{9BA8E822-8889-4826-82CF-41DFE04129EA}\packages\kb2829760\kb2829760-enu.msp;C:\ProgramData\Package Cache\{B7C61168-6AE1-4AF3-BA3D-48D7369C41F2}\packages\kb2829760\kb2829760v2-enu.msp;C:\ProgramData\Package Cache\{ABEF08E8-5C61-42C4-AD64-FC5412586B89}\packages\kb2829760\kb2829760v3-enu.msp"'
[0B88:12C4][2014-12-21T19:47:56]i000: MUX:  ExecuteError: Package (vs_professionalcoreres) failed: Error Message Id: 2902 ErrorMessage: The installer has encountered an unexpected error installing this package. This may indicate a problem with this package. The error code is 2902.
[0E44:1184][2014-12-21T19:48:47]e000: Error 0x80070643: Failed to install MSI package.
[0E44:1184][2014-12-21T19:48:47]e000: Error 0x80070643: Failed to execute MSI package.
[0B88:12C4][2014-12-21T19:48:47]e000: Error 0x80070643: Failed to configure per-machine MSI package.
[0B88:12C4][2014-12-21T19:48:47]i000: MUX:  Installation size in bytes for package: vs_professionalcoreres MaxAppDrive: 0  MaxSysDrive: 686784512  AppDrive: 0  SysDrive: 31719424
[0B88:12C4][2014-12-21T19:48:47]i000: MUX:  Return Code:0x80070643 Msi Messages:2902 Result Detail:0 Restart:None
[0B88:12C4][2014-12-21T19:48:47]i000: MUX:  Set Result: Return Code=-2147023293 (0x80070643), Error Message=2902, Result Detail=, Vital=True, Package Action=Install, Package Id=vs_professionalcoreres
[0B88:12C4][2014-12-21T19:48:47]i319: Applied execute package: vs_professionalcoreres, result: 0x80070643, restart: None
[0B88:12C4][2014-12-21T19:48:47]e000: Error 0x80070643: Failed to execute MSI package.
[0B88:12C4][2014-12-21T19:48:47]i000: MUX:  ExecutePackageBegin PackageId: vs_professionalcoreres
[0E44:1184][2014-12-21T19:48:47]i318: Skipped rollback of package: vs_professionalcoreres, action: Uninstall, already: Absent
[0B88:12C4][2014-12-21T19:48:47]i000: MUX:  Installation size in bytes for package: vs_professionalcoreres MaxAppDrive: 0  MaxSysDrive: 0  AppDrive: 0  SysDrive: 0
[0B88:12C4][2014-12-21T19:48:47]i000: MUX:  Return Code:0x0 Msi Messages:2902 Result Detail:0 Restart:None
[0B88:12C4][2014-12-21T19:48:47]i000: MUX:  Reset execution Result
[0B88:12C4][2014-12-21T19:48:47]i000: MUX:  Reset Result
```

And this log also in AppData\Local\Temp\dd_vs_community_20141221193705_101_vs_professionalcoreres.log

```
MSI (s) (54:F0) [19:47:58:111]: Note: 1: 2265 2:  3: -2147287035
MSI (s) (54:F0) [19:47:58:112]: User policy value 'DisableRollback' is 0
MSI (s) (54:F0) [19:47:58:112]: Machine policy value 'DisableRollback' is 0
Action ended 19:47:58: InstallFinalize. Return value 3.
```

And I have also found these in the same file

```
MSI (s) (54:F0) [19:48:46:815]: Note: 1: 2318 2:  
MSI (s) (54:F0) [19:48:46:820]: No System Restore sequence number for this installation.
MSI (s) (54:F0) [19:48:46:821]: Unlocking Server
MSI (s) (54:F0) [19:48:46:873]: PROPERTY CHANGE: Deleting UpdateStarted property. Its current value is '1'.
Action ended 19:48:46: INSTALL. Return value 3.
```

What is causing this problem? and how to solve it?,from the logs the error is ERROR 2902 I have googled about it and I didn't find any solutions.

[image: Installation Errors Messages]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**UPDATE :-**

I have found these in AppData\Local\ dd_vs_community_20141222103227_097_vc_compilercore86res.log

```
MSI (s) (EC:D0) [10:33:13:227]: Executing op: ActionStart(Name=CreateShortcuts,Description=Creating shortcuts,Template=Shortcut: [1])
MSI (s) (EC:D0) [10:33:13:227]: Executing op: SetTargetFolder(Folder=C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\Common7\Tools\Shortcuts\)
MSI (s) (EC:D0) [10:33:13:228]: Executing op: ShortcutCreate(Name=kqcv3hvy.win|VS2013 x86 Native Tools Command Prompt,,,FileName=%comspec%,Arguments=/k ""C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\VC\vcvarsall.bat"" x86,WorkingDir=C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\VC\,,,,ShowCmd=1,Description=Open Visual Studio 2013 x86 Native Tools Command Prompt,,,,)
MSI (s) (EC:D0) [10:33:14:309]: Note: 1: 2105 2: -2147024809 3: VS2013 x86 Native Tools Command Prompt.lnk 
MSI (s) (EC:D0) [10:33:14:310]: Executing op: ShortcutPropertyCreate(ShortcutName=kqcv3hvy.win|VS2013 x86 Native Tools Command Prompt,PropertyKey=System.AppUserModel.ExcludeFromShowInNewInstall,PropVariantValue=1)
Warning 1909.Could not create Shortcut VS2013 x86 Native Tools Command Prompt.lnk. Verify that the destination folder exists and that you can access it.
DEBUG: Error 2902:  Operation ixoShortcutPropertyCreate called out of sequence.
MSI (s) (EC:D0) [10:33:14:315]: Product: Microsoft Visual C++ 2013 32bit Compilers - ENU Resources -- The installer has encountered an unexpected error installing this package. This may indicate a problem with this package. The error code is 2902. The arguments are: ixoShortcutPropertyCreate, , 

The installer has encountered an unexpected error installing this package. This may indicate a problem with this package. The error code is 2902. The arguments are: ixoShortcutPropertyCreate, , 
MSI (s) (EC:D0) [10:33:14:327]: Note: 1: 2265 2:  3: -2147287035 
MSI (s) (EC:D0) [10:33:14:328]: User policy value 'DisableRollback' is 0
MSI (s) (EC:D0) [10:33:14:328]: Machine policy value 'DisableRollback' is 0
Action ended 10:33:14: InstallFinalize. Return value 3.
```

**Solution :-**

Firstly I give the current user full control over C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0. By clicking right click over the folder properties then security then make sure SYSTEM,Administrators and Users have Full Control and added the current user profile and gave it full control but that didn't solve the problem.
After that I have Found that  ComSpec System Variable in Environment Variables value is : %SystemRoot%\system32\cmd.exe;C:\wamp\bin\php\php5.5.12;.Changing the value to %SystemRoot%\system32\cmd.exe; solved the problem.

**EDIT :-**

Adding the current user profile to C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0. folder caused  Error 1316.The specified account already exists when I have tried to uninstall VS 2013 so I deleted that profile then I could uninstall VS 2013 Successfully.

Comment: I guess windows can be a pain when installing in enterprise setting with AppData and temp user folders on a network drive with tight permissions. I changed AppData to a local folder i created, didn't need admin privs or anything, just ran repair and it fixed install...

Answer (score 2):

My first guess for the solution of this issue is to set user access control to the lowest value.I found it worked for me.

Comment: That's right turning UAC (User Account Control) to minimum value may solve installation problems but consider reseting UAC to the highest value after installation is finished so malewares that need Admin privileges can't run on your pc without your permission.

Answer (score 1):

Probably the issue arises from updates occurences after installation.

You could try to check the
**`kb2829760`** installation in your 
`C:\ProgramData\Package Cache` directory (look at http://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/2829760).

In my system I found `C:\ProgramData\Package Cache\07D2D6FD53E7EDE1FB612619A11BBCD5530A3E56\packages\vsupdate_kb2829760\vsupdate_kb2829760.exe` that I ran with `/Uninstall /Force` flags (my issue was cleaning up orphaned components of *Visual Studio* already removed via `appwiz.cpl` and not displayed in the updates list).

Anyway I suggest to take a deep check at `C:\ProgramData\Package Cache`. For example, if you look for *vs* (`dir /s /b *vs*`)
you could check all *GUIDs* and paths that sound like probable candidates to cleanup.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem in this way: Firstly, I deactivated the Windows firewall, and then using a free program: Revo Unistaller Pro (http://www.revouninstaller.com/revo_uninstaller_free_download.html), I cleared out the old installation of Visual Studio. 
Afterwards, I used CCleaner to manually delete all the components that depend on Visual Studio:

[image]

and

[image]

Afterwards, from the command line (as administrator) I used this

```
name like 'microsoft visual%'" call uninstall /nointeractive
```

to delete the other packages. 
**note:** Repeat for SQL etc by replacing visual% in above command with sql.

Then restart the pc and try to install now Visual Studio.

Best regards